# Is there any way in nodejs to print log4js output in JSON format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, log4js-node

I am trying to get output of log4js in JSON format so I can easily trace it.
Is there any way that we have to set in configuration.json so output produced by log4js will be in JSON format?

Currently I am using following config.

```
{
 "appenders": [
{
  "category": "XXXXX",
  "type": "dateFile",
  "filename": "XXXXXXXX",
  "pattern": "-from-MM-dd",
  "layout": {
    "type": "messagePassThrough"
  }
},
{
  "category": "XXXXXXXXX",
  "type": "dateFile",
  "filename": "XXXXXXXX",
  "pattern": "-from-MM-dd",
  "layout": {
    "type": "messagePassThrough"
  }
}
 ],
"levels": {
"XXXXConfig":  "INFO",
"XXXXXjectConfig" : "INFO"
 }
}
```

and I got output is in following format :

```
DEBUG:  1458562784032 : 2016-03-21T12:19:44.4444+00:00 : Data in request: : {
"action": "XXXXXXX",
"user": {
    "username": "XXXX",
     "id" : XXXX,
    "pos" : XXXX
},
"version": 111
}
```

instead I want it in (Something like following structure) :

{"id" : "1458562784032", "time" : "2016-03-21T12:19:44.4444+00:00", "message" : "Data in request:", "data" : "{
    "action": "XXXXXXX",
    "user": {
        "username": "XXXX",
         "id" : XXXX,
        "pos: : XXXX
    },
    "version": 111
    }" }

May be there is something I missing in config.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I tried a lot for that but didn't get any solution till the time, Instead I am creating log in JSON format itself and pushing it into log file. So now I have JSON logs in my log file. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use bunyan for same purpose which logs your console log in JSON format.
Here is the npm link for node : https://www.npmjs.com/package/bunyan.

Also even if you want to use log4js then create your own pattern and write log file into JSON format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to implement this issue now, you can [add your own layouts](https://github.com/log4js-node/log4js-node/blob/master/docs/layouts.md#adding-your-own-layouts) or [pattern format](https://github.com/log4js-node/log4js-node/blob/master/docs/layouts.md#pattern).

Below is the sample code of adding your own layouts with `JSON` format

```
const log4js = require('log4js');

log4js.addLayout('json', function(config) {
  return function(logEvent) { return JSON.stringify(logEvent) + config.separator; }
});

log4js.configure({
  appenders: {
    out: { type: 'stdout', layout: { type: 'json', separator: ',' } }
  },
  categories: {
    default: { appenders: ['out'], level: 'info' }
  }
});

const logger = log4js.getLogger('json-test');
logger.info('this is just a test');
```